# Why the value is constant?

Tags: mysql

I would like to make a procedure which updates birth date, basing on personal identity number and everything works well apart from one thing. PID is taken only once and consequently the result is the same for all 200 records. How should I change this?

For example: PID of the first value is 30052766293, so birth_date = 1930-05-27,but for left PIDs result (date) is the same

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE s INT DEFAULT 0;
    abc:LOOP
    UPDATE people
      SET birth_date = (SELECT str_to_date(CONCAT('19',substring(PID,1,2),
                          substring(PID,3,2),
                          substring(PID,5,2)
                         )
                   , '%Y %m %d') FROM workers LIMIT 1);
      SET s = s+1;
      IF s>=200 
      THEN LEAVE abc; 
      END IF ;
      END LOOP;
      END $$
```

EDIT: people and workers are separate tables and both have the same column PID

Comment: So if you have `PID` in `people` already, why do you need to get it from `workers`?

Comment: Do you only want to change 200 records or all of them?

Comment: I benefit from this convenience because when I try to 'SELECT FROM' the  same table I get error like 'Can't specify target...'

Comment: There are exactly 200 records

Comment: If there were more or less than 200, would you want to change all of them or just 200?

Comment: I would like to change all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have the `PID` value in your `people` table, you can simply change your `UPDATE` to use that value. Note that since you want to change all the values in the table, you don't even need a stored procedure, you can just run this query directly:

```
UPDATE people
  SET birth_date = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('19',SUBSTRING(PID,1,2),
                                           SUBSTRING(PID,3,2),
                                           SUBSTRING(PID,5,2)
                                      )
                             , '%Y %m %d');
```

Note that it looks like you could further simplify this to:

```
UPDATE people
  SET birth_date = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('19',SUBSTRING(PID,1,6))
                             , '%Y%m%d');
```